# How to deactivate account using angularfire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am working on a project using angularfire and I would like to know if it is possible to deactivate an account using programming instead of console panel.

[image: console feature]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AngularFire definitly doesn't have a method for this, and after digging though the FireBase API reference, it doesn't look like firebase does either. Hopefully someone can correct me on this, as programmaticly managing users is a must.

Comment: Alfonso from the Firebase Auth team. There is currently no supported way to do this, but we are taking this feedback into consideration internally. Mind telling me what is your use case for this?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. A simple scenario where the administrator can prevent a user from logging in the application, such as very old users.